# How to limit repetitions in textx grammar?

Tags: peg, textx

I'm trying to create a grammar in [textx](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/).

The syntax should look like this:

```
name_a
name_a, name_b
name_a, name_b: name_c, *
name_a, name_b: name_c, *, name_d
*, name_d
*
```

Where asterisk (`*`) means "all". I want it not to repeat. Current grammar is this:

```
Subsets: ColumnsSet*;
ColumnsSet: SetItem (',' ColumnsSet)*;
SetItem: ColumnName | Star;
Star: '*';
ColumnName: name=ID (':' rename=ID)*;
```

It allows repetition of asterisk. I want to prevent such case, so that these lines are invalid:

```
name_a, *, *
name_a, *, name_b, *
*, name_a, *
```

How should I rewrite the grammar?

Is there a way to flatten the output of the nested rule: `ColumnsSet: SetItem (',' ColumnsSet)*;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your grammar. First in textX you need to use [assignments](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/grammar/#assignments) to collect relevant data. Use `*=`, `+=` style of assignment to denote many zero/one-or-more. Use [separator repetition modifiers](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/grammar/#repetition-modifiers) to avoid `Something (',' Something)*` boilerplate.

To prevent `*` happening multiple time you can register [object processor](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/metamodel/#object-processors) which can check for semantic errors.

Also, to ensure that language is line oriented you may need to look into [noskipws](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/grammar/#rule-modifiers) rule modifier.

textX is not just a parser, from the grammar it deduces meta-model of the language which [you can visualize](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/visualization/)

Here is one (probably non-complete) solution which can be a good start.

```py
from textx import metamodel_from_str, TextXSemanticError
from textx.scoping.tools import get_location

grammar = r'''
    Subsets: col_sets+=ColumnsSet;
    ColumnsSet: set_items+=SetItem[','];
    SetItem: ColumnName | Star;
    Star: '*';
    ColumnName: name=ID (':' rename=ID)?;
'''

def column_set_proc(cs):
    if len([x for x in cs.set_items if x == '*']) > 1:
        raise TextXSemanticError('Cannot use multiple * in a single line', **get_location(cs))

mm = metamodel_from_str(grammar)
mm.register_obj_processors({'ColumnsSet': column_set_proc})

# This will pass
model = mm.model_from_str(r'''name_a
name_a, name_b
name_a, name_b: name_c, *
name_a, name_b: name_c, *, name_d
*, name_d
*
''')

# Each of these raise TextXSemanticError
count = 0
for invalid in ['name_a, *, *', ' name_a, *, name_b, *', ' *, name_a, *']:
    try:
        mm.model_from_str(invalid)
    except TextXSemanticError:
        count += 1

assert count == 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I noticed the `[',']` in the hello world example, but this will help much more!